# Use a class based on dev/test/prod in Django

Tags: python, django, configuration

I'm making a Django app which will use AWS S3 and Route53 among other Amazon AWS features. To use those features when running the local server and tests, I'm going to mock their functionality using a class that overrides the AWS SDK classes. I have split my settings files according to [this RevSys recommendation.](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/)

What is the best way to use a different class based on which settings file is used? I think I could define a variable pointing to the correct class in each settings file and get the value from settings at runtime, but I feel like there is a better way.